# C# EXT (weird behaviour): ascx calls directmethod of another ascx

Tags: c#, extjs

In my project I have (among others) 2 `ascx` files. Each one has an editable grid. But when I edit a cell in the grid of UsersGrid.ascx file it calls the direct method of TrialDashboard.ascx file. The problem is solved if I put an alert() with this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

in the edit() js function of TrialDashboard.ascx, just before calling its direct method. Here is the code:

**UsersGrid.ascx**

```
<ext:XScript ID="XScript1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var edit = function (editor, e) {
            if (!(e.value === e.originalValue)) //|| (Ext.isDate(e.value) && Ext.Date.isEqual(e.value, e.originalValue)))) {
               #{DirectMethods}.UpdateRow(e.record.data.UserId, e.field, e.originalValue, e.value);

        };

        var Before = function (item,e) {
            //alert('e.record.data.UserId:'+e.record.data.UserId+'e.field:'+e.field+'e.originalValue:'+e.originalValue+'e.value:'+e.value);
            if ((e.column.id === 'ColUsersNotes' || e.column.id === 'ColUsersAssessment') && e.record.get('Role') != 'Investigator')
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
   </script>
</ext:XScript>

<ColumnModel runat="server" ID="UsersColumModel1" >
    <Columns>
       <ext:Column runat="server" ID="ColUsersEmail" DataIndex="Email" Text="Email"MinWidth="200"  Flex="2">
                                 <Editor>
                                       <ext:TextField runat="server" />
                                </Editor>
                            </ext:Column>
    </Columns>
</ColumnModel>
<SelectionModel>
           <ext:CellSelectionModel runat="server" />
            </SelectionModel>
                    <Plugins>
                        <ext:CellEditing runat="server">
                            <Listeners>
                                <BeforeEdit Handler="return Before(item, e);" />
                                <Edit Fn="edit" />
                            </Listeners>
                        </ext:CellEditing>
                    </Plugins>
```

**TrialDashboard.ascx**

```
<ext:XScript ID="XScript1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var edit = function (editor, e) {
            alert( "TD:"+e.field+ e.originalValue+ e.value e.record.data); //if alert() is here then code works as expected

            if (!(e.value === e.originalValue)) //|| (Ext.isDate(e.value) && Ext.Date.isEqual(e.value, e.originalValue)))) {
            {
                #{DirectMethods}.UpdateRo(e.record.data.id, e.record.data.Siteid, e.field, e.originalValue, e.value);
            }//#{DirectMethods}.UpdateRow(e.record.data.Siteid, e.field, e.originalValue, e.value);

        };



    </script>
</ext:XScript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `edit` function is defined twice.  Even though they are in separate ascx files, one will override the other if the names are not unique on the page where the custom controls are used.  You could try to rename them as `UsersGrid_edit` and `TrialDashboard_edit` or using some other naming convention that will ensure the names are unique.

**UsersGrid.ascx**

```
<ext:XScript ID="XScript1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var UsersGrid_edit = function (editor, e) {
            if (!(e.value === e.originalValue)) //|| (Ext.isDate(e.value) && Ext.Date.isEqual(e.value, e.originalValue)))) {
               #{DirectMethods}.UpdateRow(e.record.data.UserId, e.field, e.originalValue, e.value);

        };

        var UsersGrid_Before = function (item,e) {
            //alert('e.record.data.UserId:'+e.record.data.UserId+'e.field:'+e.field+'e.originalValue:'+e.originalValue+'e.value:'+e.value);
            if ((e.column.id === 'ColUsersNotes' || e.column.id === 'ColUsersAssessment') && e.record.get('Role') != 'Investigator')
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
   </script>
</ext:XScript>

<ColumnModel runat="server" ID="UsersColumModel1" >
    <Columns>
       <ext:Column runat="server" ID="ColUsersEmail" DataIndex="Email" Text="Email"MinWidth="200"  Flex="2">
                                 <Editor>
                                       <ext:TextField runat="server" />
                                </Editor>
                            </ext:Column>
    </Columns>
</ColumnModel>
<SelectionModel>
           <ext:CellSelectionModel runat="server" />
            </SelectionModel>
                    <Plugins>
                        <ext:CellEditing runat="server">
                            <Listeners>
                                <BeforeEdit Handler="return UsersGrid_Before(item, e);" />
                                <Edit Fn="UsersGrid_edit" />
                            </Listeners>
                        </ext:CellEditing>
                    </Plugins>
```

**TrialDashboard.ascx**

```
<ext:XScript ID="XScript1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var TrialDashboard_edit = function (editor, e) {
            alert( "TD:"+e.field+ e.originalValue+ e.value e.record.data); //if alert() is here then code works as expected

            if (!(e.value === e.originalValue)) //|| (Ext.isDate(e.value) && Ext.Date.isEqual(e.value, e.originalValue)))) {
            {
                #{DirectMethods}.UpdateRo(e.record.data.id, e.record.data.Siteid, e.field, e.originalValue, e.value);
            }//#{DirectMethods}.UpdateRow(e.record.data.Siteid, e.field, e.originalValue, e.value);

        };



    </script>
</ext:XScript>
```